# Is a S4 class an object?

Tags: r, r-s4

From *Extending R* by Chamber, I heard that everything existing in R is an object (which is also true in Python: a class in Python is an object, the class of a class is a metaclass.). Is a S4 class an object? What is the type of a S4 class?

```
> setClass("Person",
+ slots = c(
+ name = "character",
+ age = "numeric"
+ )
+ )

> typeof(Person)
Error in typeof(Person) : object 'Person' not found
> typeof("Person")
[1] "character"

> attributes(Person)
Error: object 'Person' not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you consider one of the answers as sufficient to beaccepted?

Comment: yes. Thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, everything in R is an object, yet classes themselves are not directly objects.

> We can do object oriented programming in R. In fact, everything in R is an object.
> An object is a data structure having some attributes and methods which act on its attributes.
> Class is a blueprint for the object. We can think of class like a sketch (prototype) of a house. It contains all the details about the floors, doors, windows etc. Based on these descriptions we build the house.

(From [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/object-class-introduction/)).

#### S3

Think about S3 objects. You never really assign them, you just define a method that works for this specific class:

```
summary.mnist <- function(x) print("HELLO!")
x <- 3
class(x) <- "mnist"
summary(x)
# [1] "HELLO!"
typeof(mnist)
# Error in typeof(mnist) : object 'mnist' not found
```

#### S4

Nevertheless, when working with S4, to use a Class you usually define a generator function via `setClass`. This generator function then is an object of type closure, yet the class itself is not an object:

```
Person <- setClass("Person",
         slots = c(
         name = "character",
         age = "numeric"
         )
         )
typeof(Person)
# [1] "closure"
myPerson <- Person()
typeof(myPerson)
# [1] "S4"
```

Comment: Thanks. The way that you assign setClass() return to a variable and the way you create an object of the class is different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/61011212/. I was wondering which one is preferred?

Comment: Since both is possible, this is definitely opinion based: I see "my" approach as the default since this is the usage in the examples of `?setClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this problem is that the object returned by `setClass()` is an object of class `classGeneratorFunction`. It's definitely an object. Also, since functions in R are also considered objects, it's an object.

We'll illustrate by adjusting the code from the original post.

```
personGenerator <- setClass("Person",
                            slots = c(name = "character",
                                      age = "numeric"))

aPerson <- personGenerator()
```

At this point, we have a class generator function that generates objects of type `Person`, and an instance of `Person`.

We can see this with the `str()` function.

```
str(aPerson)
> str(aPerson)
Formal class 'Person' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
  ..@ name: chr(0) 
  ..@ age : num(0)
```

Similarly, we can print the structure of the `personGenerator()` function.

```
> str(personGenerator)
Formal class 'classGeneratorFunction' [package "methods"] with 3 slots
  ..@ .Data    :function (...)  
  ..@ className: chr "Person"
  .. ..- attr(*, "package")= chr ".GlobalEnv"
  ..@ package  : chr ".GlobalEnv"
>
```

Going back to the Chambers quote, it's recounted in Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R* as:

> To understand computations in R, two slogans are helpful.
>
> -- Everything that exists is an object
>
> -- Everything that happens is a function call
>
> John Chambers quoted in *Advanced R*, p. 79.

Since the original question was a bit ambiguous, if "S4 class" refers to the thing represented by the return value of `setClass()`, an object of type `classGeneratorFunction`, this is indeed an object.  However, if the "S4 class" in the original question refers to the content in the arguments of `setClass()`, the thing representing `Person` is not an object until code instantiates it as illustrated above with the `personGenerator()` function.

Comment: so, what is your answer to the question? I have argued "No" because the class itself is not an object (as it is in python) but only the generator function is. I think this is even clearer for S3 classes. Or qhat do you think?

Comment: The way I read the question, `setClass()` returns an object of type `classGeneratorFunction`. The thing returned by `setClass()` is an object. The inputs to `setClass()` are arguments, which in R are also objects. That said, the combination of these arguments into an instance of `Person` is the result of another function call, which I named `personGenerator()` for the sake of clarity.  Until a line of code uses `personGenerator()` to create an instance of `Person`, `Person` per se does not exist and therefore is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a S4 class through `setClass()`, an object of class `classRepresentation` is created (ironically `classRepresentation` is itself a S4 class). This object defines the class and is used when an instance of the class is created through `new()`. At the user level, this `classRepresentation` is usually invisible as it is stored in the namespace of the package which defines it or in a cached class table (`methods:::.classTable`). Still, a user may obtain the definition through `getClassDef()`.

Some answers point out that `setClass()` returns a `classGeneratorFunction`. However the returned `classGeneratorFunction` is not what defines the class. In fact, when defining S4 classes it is a common practise to ignore the return value of `setClass()` and instead write a custom class constructor function through `new()`. Here is an example:

```
setClass("Person",
         slots = c(
         name = "character",
         age = "numeric"
         )
         )

# This ensures that every instance of Person is
# always initialized with a name and an age
Person <- function(name, age) {
    new("Person", name=name, age=age)
}

aPerson <- Person("John", 50)
> str(aPerson)
Formal class 'Person' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
  ..@ name: chr "John"
  ..@ age : num 50

# Get the class definition itself
PersonDef <- getClassDef("Person")
> str(PersonDef)
Formal class 'classRepresentation' [package "methods"] with 11 slots
  ..@ slots     :List of 2
  .. ..$ name: chr "character"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "package")= chr "methods"
  .. ..$ age : chr "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "package")= chr "methods"
  ..@ contains  : list()
  ..@ virtual   : logi FALSE
  ..@ prototype :Formal class 'S4' [package ""] with 0 slots
 list()
  .. .. ..$ name: chr(0) 
  .. .. ..$ age : num(0) 
  ..@ validity  : NULL
  ..@ access    : list()
  ..@ className : chr "Person"
  .. ..- attr(*, "package")= chr ".GlobalEnv"
  ..@ package   : chr ".GlobalEnv"
  ..@ subclasses: list()
  ..@ versionKey:<externalptr> 
  ..@ sealed    : logi FALSE
```