# What is the `attr(,"package")` for an S4 object?

Tags: r

What does the `attr(,"package")` in the following output for an S4 object mean?

- Is it an attribute of an S4 object?
- Is  `".GlobalEnv"` the value of the attribute for an S4 object?
- Is the attribute related to the class attribute of an S4 object? (They are shown without a blank line separating them.)

Output:

```
> setClass("Person",
+ slots = c(
+ name = "character",
+ age = "numeric"
+ )
+ )

> john <- new("Person", name = "John Smith", age = NA_real_)
> typeof(john)
[1] "S4"
> attributes(john)
$name
[1] "John Smith"

$age
[1] NA

$class
[1] "Person"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at the "Classes and Packages" section of the `setClass()` man page, which you can access via the R command `help("setClass")`

Comment: I find myself referring to [this resource](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)  whenever I need to deal with S4 objects.

Comment: @duckmayr What does `attr(,"package")` in the   output for an S4 object mean?